# Ubuntu and CentOS, are they one and the same?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

A setup is being done for some deployment work, person A had requested for a VM with Ubuntu install on it. From what I read and understand, Ubuntu is built on Linux. Person B marked the request as complete and delivered a server that person A can use, but on logging in the person A has noticed that it isn't Ubuntu but CentOS 7.

So A and B have been going at it the entire day, person A claims that having CentOS instead of Ubuntu is going to make a joke of his plans and he'd have to redo whatever he has already done.

At one point during the conversation person B said that the machine is Ubuntu, but it has the CentOS flavour installed, to which person A objected. Is that a true statement? Isn't Ubuntu in itself a flavour of Linux? Is there a CentOS version of Ubuntu out there? (I couldn't find one).

My questions are,

1. Aren't both CentOS and Ubuntu built on Linux kernel? What's the big deal then?
2. Are there packages/software that'd run on Ubuntu but not on CentOS?
3. Wouldn't both have just the same command line stuff to work on with?
4. Is there a CentOS (or any other) version of Ubuntu out there?

Comment: Using your Windows background, you can say that Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 share a large amount of their code base so its not a big deal  to install one instead of the other.

Comment: Suggest you spin off questions 1, 3, and 4 into separate questions by clicking on [edit], copying then deleting them, and leave # 2 as your question here. We're building a knowledge base with all these questions and answers, and need laser-tight focus in the questions. That might get this taken off hold, and you can ask the other questions separately if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're rather different. 'A' is right, and 'B' is not accurate in claiming any version of Ubuntu has been installed. There are [multiple versions, or 'flavors'](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours), of Ubuntu out there, but CentOS is not one of them.

The Linux kernel is so small that multiple different sets of OS components must be added to make it functional as a desktop, laptop, or server, and some apps demand one set of OS components (a [distribution, or 'distro'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)) and will not work in another distro.

There are multiple branches of the giant tree which is Linux. [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com) is descended from [Debian](https://www.debian.org/). [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) is descended from [RedHat](https://www.redhat.com/en).

[This list](https://lwn.net/Distributions/) gives you an introduction to the different families, and [this graphic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg) shows how different versions have evolved. [Here's a comparison of Debian and Fedora](https://medium.com/linode-cube/choosing-a-linux-distro-part-2-debian-and-fedora-63bea212e6de), plus a [comparison of Arch and CentOS](https://medium.com/linode-cube/picking-a-linux-distro-part-1-arch-and-centos-8c0c55170dde), Fedora being the pioneer distribution from which RedHat and CentOS find innovations to selectively adopt.

The most obvious thing included in a distro is the Desktop Environment 'DE', and both CentOS and Ubuntu now use the same DE as default ('GNOME'). However, there are [many other DEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Examples_of_desktop_environments) in Linux, whereas Windows only has one DE for a version (the DE of Windows 3.1 is different from XP which is different from Windows 7 which is different from Windows 8 which differs from Windows 10).

However, two different distros with the same DE won't work the same way, or run all of the same apps, so although the DE is the first thing someone encounters, it surely is not the most important, and the differences between CentOS and Ubuntu will be apparent when the user tries to add an app.

Answer (score 3):

Calling CentOS a flavour of Ubuntu is nonsense. CentOS can be called a flavour of RedHat and Ubuntu can be called a flavour of Debian.

You probably didn't bother to google CentOS and Ubuntu.

1. both CentOS and Ubuntu use a Linux kernel, but there is more to a system than the kernel.
2. Depends on the package and what effort you are willing to invest, and whether sources are available or not.
3. They may or may not have the same command line stuff, also depending on the versions of both, but the configuration is different.
4. As already mentioned, there is no CentOS version of Ubuntu.

I'm not sure I would trust this person B to properly setup a Linux system, whether CentOS, Ubuntu or any other.

Comment: It's better to call CentOS(and Red Hat) a flavor of Fedora.

Comment: I did google, but all I got was CentOS vs Ubuntu comparisons but did not find anything that used these two terms interchangeably. Thank you for the inputs, that's helpful.

Comment: @NasirRiley you have your distribution history mixed up.  RedHat 1.0 was released in 1995, and Fedora Core 1.0 in 2003.   RedHat even had pre-release versions available before that.  Both Fedora and CentOS are RedHat derivative distributions, while Ubuntu is a Debian derivative distribution.

Comment: @Tim Kennedy The Fedora Project was formed from a merger of Red Hat and Fedora. As Fedora is upstream from RHEL and CentOS, it's more appropriate to call the latter two flavors of Fedora.

Comment: @Tim nowadays RHEL derives from Fedora (with significant changes) and CentOS derives from RHEL (much more closely). RHEL 7 was based on Fedora 19/20, RHEL 8 was based on Fedora 28.

Comment: @NasirRiley (and Stephen Kitt) Thank you both for clarifying that.  Apparently, I'm old, and so is my info. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several fundamental differences between the two, especially when configuring them. If a way of configuring Ubuntu has been worked out for many hours or days by someone familiar with Ubuntu, it can potentially take days or weeks to become familiar with CentOS’s ways of doing things properly (including important things like security configuration) and then hours or days to figure out how to properly configure the desired applications running on CentOS.

As far as getting the applications up and running, one important way they differ is that their software package managers (that properly install software in a way that makes it easy to update and uninstall) are completely different:

- the package manager of one cannot be installed on the other to avoid this
- each package manager will (not can, but will) provide different versions of the same software with different default configurations, which can include different configuration procedures for those different versions if that procedure was changed in the software in an update
- the same application can have different package names on different package managers
- the same application can be provided in one package manager but not the other, which means that they have to spend extra time working out how to install it cleanly.

B is either new to Linux, which makes their opinion on the matter frankly worthless, or B is lying rather than ignorant when they claim that CentOS is a flavor of Ubuntu, which is why they would have installed CentOS to begin with: they’re probably somewhat familiar with CentOS and thus realize that that familiarity is very important in getting ***their*** work done, not caring about A getting their work done.